# Kubernetes nginx ingress redirects without path prefix

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a few apps that I am trying to get ingress set up for, the apps themselves will redirect to other urls for example:

`app1host:8080/auth/logout?redirect_uri=/`

I am trying to create a rule that allows the redirect to redirect back to my path but have not had any success.

`app1host:8080/auth/logout?redirect_uri=/ -> domain.com/app1/auth/logout?redirect_uri=/`

The current code redirects me back to the root folder domain.com/

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: webservices
  uid: 96336c73-dcae-4c69-b1d3-0eacf8902173
  resourceVersion: '356090'
  generation: 63
  creationTimestamp: '2021-03-21T09:51:34Z'
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  managedFields:
    - manager: nginx-ingress-controller
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
      time: '2021-03-21T14:19:21Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
    - manager: dashboard
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
      time: '2021-03-23T22:51:34Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: {}
            f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: {}
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
      time: '2021-03-23T23:06:04Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
        f:spec:
          f:rules: {}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: app1
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /app2(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: app2
              servicePort: 8181
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 192.168.0.250
```

Comment: Hello, for the readability please attach the source manifest of your `Ingress` rather than the output of `$ kubectl get ing NAME -o yaml`. Also, could you please add in steps how the communication should happen from a client perspective?

Comment: I'm fairly new to kubernetes and ingress. I installed the nginx with a helm chart. Are you referring to the nginx.conf file?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `proxy-redirect-from` and `proxy-redirect-to`:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: "http://app1host:8080/"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: "http://example.com/app1/"
```

Comment: Would I change the application to NodePort and then add those lines?

I tried that but I end up with a 404.

Comment: What do you mean with change the application to NodePort? The services can stay as ClusterIP as they are being accessed by the ingress. Are you getting 404 now when you are accesing  `app1host:8080/auth/logout?redirect_uri=/`?

Comment: If its staying as ClusterIP what would I put as app1host?

When I use ``nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: / `` and set my app path to / it works.

But when I set the app path to /app1 it gets redirected to the root path. Is it possible to have it direct to multiple sub paths based on the application?

Comment: ClusterIP has nothing to do with the path, thats just a service running behind your ingress. So everything should go through ingress. So `rewrite-target` is what the path will look like when it gets forwarded to the service. Right now you have `/$2`, and in your path you have `/app1(/|$)(.*)`, so only the second regex will be passed which means that the `/app1/` will be removed and if you send request to `example.com/app1/login`, the service will receive `example.com/login`

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the http root in the application it self, now it works as intended.